# git error: unable to access The requested URL

Tags: linux, git, networking

After re-installing git with the following commands that were advised by someone

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get install git-daemon-sysvinit
sudo apt-get install git-all
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

I get the following error when trying to pull or push: 
    `fatal: unable to access [url]. The requested url returned error: 502.`
Attempts to re-install git again also failed. It seems that I have removed some package. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This sounds a problem with the remote URL pointing to your Git repo provider.  Who is your Git provider?

Comment: It's local. Access to repository by URL from web browser works fine. But when it comes to terminal, git has problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of effort, I found that the problem was caused by Firefox proxy settings. Setting a proxy in firefox was creating corresponding variables in **/etc/environment** which remained even when I chose "no proxy" option in Firefox. Clearing them manually solved the problem.